# Merge elements of dataframe in list based on partial match of names

Tags: r, list, dataframe, merge, cbind

I have a list:

```
lst <- list(a1=dfa1, a2=dfa2, b1=dfb1, b2=dfb2)

dfa1 <- data.frame(x=c(1:5), y=c(2, 5, 7, 9, 10))
dfa2 <- data.frame(x=c(1:6), y=c(3, 8, 1, 2, 4, 13))
dfb1 <- data.frame(x=c(1:4), y=c(7, 9, 3, 2))
dfb2 <- data.frame(x=c(1:7), y=c(9, 3, 5, 1, 7, 9, 11))
```

Base on the partial element match 'a' and 'b', I want column bind the dataframem and the new list should look like below:

```
new_list
$a
  x  y1 y2
1 1  2  3
2 2  5  8
3 3  7  1
4 4  9  2
5 5 10  4

$b
  x y1 y2
1 1 7  9
2 2 9  3
3 3 3  5
4 4 2  1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a method with `lapply` and `Reduce`. `lapply` iterates through the letters "a" and "b" and applies `Reduce` to the list elements whose names contain the current letter. `Reduce` applies the `merge` function to the two data.frames, merging by the variable "x" and adding the desired suffixes with the given argument. Thanks to zx8754's suggestion, I added `seq_along(grep(let, names(lst)))` to allow the final names of the variables to increase by the number of group members.

```
myList <- lapply(c("a", "b"), function(let)
                              setNames(Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by="x"),
                                              lst[grep(let, names(lst))]),
                                     c("x", paste0("y", seq_along(grep(let, names(lst)))))))
[[1]]
  x y1 y2
1 1  2  3
2 2  5  8
3 3  7  1
4 4  9  2
5 5 10  4

[[2]]
  x y1 y2
1 1  7  9
2 2  9  3
3 3  3  5
4 4  2  1
```

To add names to the list it is probably easiest to do this afterward,

```
names(myList) <- c("a", "b")
```

You could also start with the vector

myVec <- c("a", "b")

and then use it in the `lapply` and in the `names` line.

Comment: Ah was just typing up the answer. Maybe better to tie the suffixes to the length of matching list of dataframes, in this case there are 2 dfs with "a", might be more than 2, makes sense?

Comment: @lmo thank you! I actually have more than four (two duplicates) elements, and so it's better if the new list has element name of the partial matched part.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @zx8754. Added a `seq_along`. Sorry about the quick draw.

Comment: @lmo I appreciate you solution. Any idea to add element names? Then I can tell if [[1]] comes from a1+a2 or b1+b2.

Comment: @lmo, Thank you! The problem is that my element name is not in order, it's not like: a1, a2, b1, b2; My real list has more than 20 elements, and some are duplicate, some are triplicate. It's petty much: c1, a1, b1, b2, d1, b3, c2, a2, d2, d3. So do you think add names afterward can differentiate them?

Comment: As long as the numeric values are in order, or you don't mind that they're not in order, then you're fine. This is taken care of by the order supplied to `lapply` and by `grep`.